# Some questions about rename a package which is in the gen folder for Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded a project from the Internet, and I wanted to rename all the classes in this project. However, there was something wrong in the gen folder. I can not rename the class which was in the gen folder. I can find the reason whatever I try my best to change it. Please help me to sort it out, thanks.

[image: rename the package in gen folder]

[image: rename]

[image: there is an error]

[image: rename finished but the old name still here]

Comment: Why don't you take screen captures instead of pictures? They would look much better...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should rename package in AndroidManifest.xml first.

Comment: Open AndroidManifest.xml and edit this part (package section): `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.your.package.name" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">`

Answer (score 1):

Rename your package. TO make Eclipse notice that, the simplest approach would be to press right mouse button over your project name in Package Explorer, then select `Android Tools` then `Rename Application Package`. In case of problems you may remove all content of gen, do 
"Project" -> "Clean" and try to rebuild.